# copy n char* inside one other

Tags: c++, copy

I bind a UUID  value from a SQL SERVER colomn (via Qt Sql module) into a QUuid object.
After that I have to assign it into a in-house uuid object by using a assign function which take a char* as parameter.

QUuid expose several char* as public members, so I have to built a char * of 16 bytes with the several char * QUuid's members.

namely, copy :

```
char buff0;
char buff1;
char buff2[2];
char buff3[4];
char buff4[8];
```

inside

```
char final[16];
```

I have used memcpy to do this task like that :

```
int accu = 0;    
memcpy(final, &buff0, sizeof(buff0)); 
accu += sizeof(buff1);
memcpy(final+accu, &buff1, sizeof(buff1));
accu += sizeof(buff2);
memcpy(final+accu, buff2, sizeof(buff2));
accu += sizeof(buff3);
memcpy(final+accu, buff3, sizeof(buff3));
accu += sizeof(buff4);
memcpy(final+accu, buff4, sizeof(buff4));
```

but I find this manner of doing not really readable and maintanable.
I'm looking for a more elegant manner to do this task. By elegant I mean with less line of codes and/or less arithmetics.

Comment: don't really understand the wish to close my question, because it's a real problem I encounter today, and except a long list of memcpy I am wondering if a better solution doesn't exists

Comment: I can see two reasons to close this question.  1) You haven't shown us what you have tried, suggesting you just want us to write this for you.  2) You haven't defined what "most elegant" means.

Comment: hum ok I see let me edit my question so

Comment: @John Dibling: what about my edit ?

Comment: @Guillaume07:  Halfway there.  What's "ugly" about what you've posted?  We can't know what you're looking for unless you tell us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a C++11 STL version.

```
char* out = final;
out = std::copy_n(&buff0, 1, out);
out = std::copy_n(&buff1, 1, out);
out = std::copy_n(buff2, 2, out);
out = std::copy_n(buff3, 4, out);
out = std::copy_n(buff4, 8, out);
```

Comment: buff0 and buff1 need to be prefix by &

Comment: would like to select this one too as best answer but have to choose

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use an union so that you can use either definition inter changeably.

Answer (score 1):

Use x86 assembly

```
;; FASM/NASM syntax
MOV    esi, final
MOVZX  eax, byte [buf0]
MOVZX  ebx, byte [buf1]
MOVZX  ecx, word [buf2]
MOV    edx, dword [buf3] 
MOV    byte [esi], al
MOV    byte [esi+1], bl
MOV    eax, dword [buf4]
MOV    ebx, dword [buf4+4]
MOV    word [esi+2], cx
MOV    dword [esi+4], edx
MOV    dword [esi+8], eax
MOV    dword [esi+12], ebx
```

Or how about making a wild assumption that all of the memory for the buf's is allocated linearly (without padding) and just use one memcpy

```
memcpy(final, buf0, 16)
```

Comment: Don't make a wild assumption.  It will be wrong when you least expect it to, and then good luck debugging it.

Comment: nice wild assumption by the way :) but dangerous yeah

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield - the original question was "what is the COOLEST way to..." Obviously, cool-kids don't worry about such matters hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

```
memcpy(&final[0], &buff0, 1);
memcpy(&final[1], &buff1, 1);
memcpy(&final[2], &buff2[0], 2);
memcpy(&final[4], &buff3[0], 4);
memcpy(&final[8], &buff4[0], 8);
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, below is a C++ 2011 solution which creates a statically checked `copy()` function: it accepts `char`s and arrays of `char`s as argument and requires exactly the amount of `char`s to be added to fill the first array being passed. Of course, the static check could be removed as needed. The original version had a few typos and omissions.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int constexpr size(char const&) { return 1; }
template <int Size>
int constexpr size(char const(&)[Size]) { return Size; }
template <typename T0, typename... T>
int constexpr size(T0 const& arg0, T const&... args) {
    return size(arg0) + size(args...);
}

char* copy_intern(char* to, char c) { *to = c; return ++to; }
template <int Size>
char* copy_intern(char* to, char const (&array)[Size]) {
    return std::copy(array, array + Size, to);
}

template <typename T0, typename... T>
char* copy_intern(char* to, T0 const& arg0, T const&... args) {
    return copy_intern(copy_intern(to, arg0), args...);
}

template <int Total, typename... T>
void copy(char (&to)[Total], T const&... args)
{
    static_assert(Total == size(args...), "wrong argument size");
    copy_intern(to, args...);
}

int main()
{
    char buff0    = 'a';
    char buff1    = 'b';
    char buff2[2] = { 'c', 'd' };
    char buff3[4] = { 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' };
    char buff4[8] = { 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p' };
    char final[16];

    copy(final, buff0, buff1, buff2, buff3, buff4);
    *std::copy(final, final + 16,
               std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout)) = '\n';
}
```

Note that the first two `copy_intern()` functions can be used in C++ 2003, as well, to deduce the type and size of the argument. That is, with these function, possibly renamed as deemed suitable, you could get something which, at least, picks up the sizes automatically:

```
    char* tmp = final;
    tmp = copy_intern(tmp, buff0);
    tmp = copy_intern(tmp, buff1);
    tmp = copy_intern(tmp, buff2);
    tmp = copy_intern(tmp, buff3);
    tmp = copy_intern(tmp, buff4);
```

Comment: yes nice one unfortunatly I'm working under msvc so don't have variadic template.

Comment: definitely the smartest way to do it!

Comment: even with template<typename T0, typename... T> above last add function the code still doesn't compile,It seems there is a problem with variadic maybe with the end of the 'recursion'

Comment: Currently, I can't try the code. I will fix it when I have access to a decent compiler. It may require use if r-value references...